# Errors while installing PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, anaconda, pyqt5

[image]

So I'm completely new to PyQt and I have absolutely no idea how to install, and run it. Most online sources are saying to simply write 'pip install pyqt5' in CMD, but I'm getting errors as listed in the photo link above. I run python from Anaconda so I'm using that, but I don't see any issues with why it wouldn't work. I tried to put the pyqt folder into the directory that the console was reading but the errors persist. Any ideas? Thanks!

Errors: 
(base) C:\Users\TMNT5>pip install pyqt5
Collecting pyqt5
  Using cached PyQt5-5.14.2-5.14.2-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38-none-win_amd64.whl (52.9 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5-sip<13,>=12.7 in c:\users\tmnt5\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pyqt5) (12.7.2)
ERROR: spyder 4.0.1 requires pyqtwebengine<5.13; python_version >= "3", which is not installed.
ERROR: spyder 4.0.1 has requirement pyqt5<5.13; python_version >= "3", but you'll have pyqt5 5.14.2 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: pyqt5
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\Users\TMNT5\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\QtCore.pyd'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Comment: Please add your errors and code in text mode as stated in our guidelines on: [how to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're not using Python 3 to install PyQt5.

```
pip install python-qt5
```

Installs unofficial PyQt5 via PyPI for Python 2.7 64-bit on Windows

Github for this here: https://github.com/pyqt/python-qt5

Comment: Seems to have worked thank you! I do have another question though. I saw that you can turn your ui file into a py file by running pyuic5 -x filename filename, but I get the message "'pyuic5' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." Any thoughts?